# Can basis vectors have fractions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I was diagonalizing a matrix in a book, and one of the basis vectors was [3/2, 1], after doing the problem, the answer in the book was different than mine. It came with an explanation, and in it the basis vector was [3,2]. They are the same thing, just multiples of each other, so I was curious, is it mandatory to take fractions out of a basis vector?

Answer (score 5):

It is not. If $v$ is a member of some basis, then we can substitute $cv$ for any non-zero constant $c$ of the reals (or the underlying field in the general case).

Comment: So does that mean I just have to do this when diagonalizing matrices? Because the answer this gave me for the original matrix taken to the power of 8 was definitely different than the one in the book?

Comment: Well, you might want to offer more context about the specific question. There might have been a reason they expected a certain scaling of the basis, but I'm not seeing it. In fact, in some contexts an *orthonormal* basis is requested, which requires that the norms of the vectors equal one, and that they're orthogonal to each other.

Comment: I don't think you said what you mean - if $v$ is a vector in some basis, then $cv$ is definitely not in the basis unless $c=1$! But you can replace $v$ by $cv$ and you will have another basis for the same space.

Comment: @Matt: thanks, you're right. I've changed the wording to hopefully make that clearer.

Comment: @tokola If the vectors in the basis you found are just scalar multiples of the vectors in the solution from the book you should end up with the same diagonal matrix that they have. So maybe you made a mistake when calculating $P^{-1}AP$ or when calculating the power you mention. By the way, funny nickname.

Comment: I have the same diagonal matrix, the problem is when I do P−1 A P, the inverse of P and P are smaller than they would be if I took the fractions out of them.

Comment: If your verifying calculation of $P^{-1}AP$ isn't working, you probably calculated $P^{-1}$ incorrectly. That diagonalization is in no way contingent on the scaling on basis vectors.

Comment: "the inverse of P and P are smaller than they would be if I took the fractions out of them." This suggests a conceptual error. If I multiply P by a number to "clear out the fractions", then the inverse will be *divided* by that number. That is: if $Q=a\cdot P$, then $Q^{-1} = (1/a) \cdot P^{-1}$. So again, the scaling of $P$ is irrelevant; any scaling you choose will be cancelled out by the resulting inverse scaling of $P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the answer is no, it is not mandatory - but there is some terminological confusion both in the question and other answers, which I will try to say something about.

You shouldn't really say that $(3,2)$ and $(\frac{3}{2},1)$ are the same thing - they aren't - but they are scalar multiples of one another. This means they are both bases for the same $1$-dimensional space (although not the same basis). Since you mention a matrix, you are probably looking for eigenvectors (i.e. a basis of each eigenspace), so it might be less confusing to say eigenvector than basis vector (or not, depending on context).

One further point - more things are vector spaces than $\mathbb{Q}^n$, so it doesn't even always make sense to "take out fractions". (Even in $\mathbb{R}^n$, no scalar multiple of $(1,\pi)$ has integer entries, and there are vector spaces like the set of continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, whose elements aren't "lists of numbers").

Comment: Why would you expect *integer* entries when removing fractions? Rather, when the vector space is $\,F^n$ and the field $F$ is the quotient field of a domain $D$ then removing fractions would mean finding a basis with elements in $D$. Thus can be achieved by multiplying through by a common denominator when the vector space is finite dimensional. $\ $

Comment: @Bill Since my point was that the operation of clearing denominators doesn't make sense in general, it didn't seem worth identifying the most general situation in which it does makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are right and they are also right. This is because multiplication by non-zero constants does not affect the span of the basis nor the linear independence of the vectors in that basis. You should be able to see this quite obviously once you think about it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I thought, but my answer for the matrix taken to the power of 8 was wrong, is this just required when diagonalizing?

Comment: No, it's not required there either. If you have $A=VDV^{-1}$, then $A^8=VD^8V^{-1}$, and the scaling still doesn't matter.